# publishing android applications with map instances

Tags: android, google-maps, keystore

i recently published an app on the play store that uses uses google map but the map instance is not showing up on any phone. what went wrong?  do  need two keystones for a google map application or? the application is just blank now but o y computers ADV the map instance is showing properly. if i send the apk file to someone else. the same thing happens.

Answer (score 2):

Probably your key is wrong, when you publish an app in play store, you must sign it with a certificate. So, when you are developing your app  it is signed with a debug certificate, it may be that your key is using the FingerPrint of the debug certificate and not the right certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Google map key need to be updated for signed APK. Google map loaded in your emulator because you register your application with system SHA1 KEY FOR DEBUG.KEYSTOR.

But when you create signed APK then you generate the new keystore file and SHA1 KEY for signed APK not matched so Google map unable load.

Solution: You can get SHA1 KEY for your release keystore file using this command:

```
 keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

> And add this SHA1 KEY to google console project. Or create new project
>   at google console with different SHA1 key and get google map key and
>   update it in application and then sign APK with same kestore file and
>   then upload to playstore